# JQuery each doesn't work for <object> in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, svg

JQuery.each returns "function anonymous" for the `<object>` elements in Google Chrome. It is OK for other elements.

How can I solve this?

Here we have three elements with 'icon-white' class:

```
<object class = 'icon-white' data="http://konradpapala.beep.pl/test/040__file_delete.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>

<object class = 'icon-white' data="http://konradpapala.beep.pl/test/040__file_delete.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>

<div class = 'icon-white'>
 this works
</div>
```

And here's the JavaScript code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(function(){
            $('.icon-white').each(function(){
                console.log(this);
        })
})
```

Edit, here is an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NpbVPLMvqo0Y2OfPrDbP?p=preview

What we can see in console is: twice an "anonymous function" returned, and once (correctly) a `<div>` element.

Comment: to get `jQuery Object` use `$` `console.log($(this));
`

Comment: @shu - thanks, but it's not about getting a jquery object or not... JQuery shouldn't return a 'function', but instead a HTML element. Even if I do $(this) (just for testing, I knew It wouldn't work :) it simply wraps a function in JQuery object.

Comment: @freedomn-m - thanks, I didn't know I needed to click "freeze", otherwise only I could see the code :) now it's done.

Comment: @konrad_firm your problem is the first comment from shu. https://jsfiddle.net/yq8ybtzd/ See it working perfectly with `$(this)`.

Comment: And this is an update with the normal `this` from your code https://jsfiddle.net/yq8ybtzd/1/

Comment: This should be closed by offtopic reason typographical error.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude wait... you say, that this is OK, that in case of `<object>` it returns a function, and in case of `<div>` it returns a html element? And only in Google Chrome? (FF works fine). If I do `$(this)`, I still get a function..... unless in case of `<div>` - then I get a Jquery object having a html element.

Comment: Oh my god. Sorry for the confusion. I'm using Firefox and it works fine with jQuery object. Maybe is a bug in Chrome or a bug in jQuery executed in chrome

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude no problem :) Thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#htmlobjectelement) defines that HTMLObjectElement has a legacy caller.

[This](http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#call) says that objects with legacy callers have [[Call]].

And then we look [in this specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and see that objects that have [[Call]] are functions.

So it's your expectations that need adjusting rather than Chrome.

Although Firefox also returns Function, it seems that jQuery intercepts this and converts the return back to an Object element but it doesn't do this for Chrome which would seem to suggest that there is a jQuery bug here.

Comment: `console.log(this)` have an empty function. Completely empty. No callers, nothing at all. Change to jQuery object is different. `console.log($(this))` produces the expected behaviour for OP

Comment: @robert-longson, thanks, I suspect this is the answer, and I'll accept it (as soon as SO will allow me),  but why FF displays a `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/icons/040__file_delete.svg" class="smallicon-white icon-white">` text, which, BTW, I expected?

Comment: Firefox is correct too. Must be jQuery wrapping and breaking Firefox somehow. https://bug1248367.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=8719453 prints Function in the Firefox console. Maybe jquery's wrapping for either Chrome or Firefox is broken.

Comment: This will be fine if `$(this)` doesn't produce that. `$(this)` is NOT  a native `HTMLObjectElement`, so is a serious error.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude - thanks. One more thing - this is the first time when I hear that a html element is a ... function o_O Do you know where I can find a list of those strange html elements?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude jQuery should wrap things consistently for Firefox and Chrome and it appears not to be doing that, despite both UAs returning a sensible raw result.

Comment: @konrad_firm in the HTML specification.

Comment: There is in the link that @RobertLongson attach: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation . But this is for the native `console.log(this)` , but in `console.log($(this))` you must not get a native html element, you'll obtain a jQuery object, is because of this I think firefox + jquery is working fine but chrome + jquery is working wrong.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I agree, it seems to be a jquery issue rather than a Chrome issue.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, I suspect I can find this in HTML specification, but this is a very big documentation :( But I'll try to find it.

Comment: Ok, we agree completely that is a jquery issue , **but in chrome** `:)`. I see a lot of problems in chrome, suspicious...

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thanks too. Now I have a lot of reading, really, I've never heard of a HTML element being a function :) Thank you both!